# Botbuilder 4. Few bots on one app service

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

We want to build SAAS platform based on ms botbuilder. Specifically now we want to have many telegram bots on one backend (web app), instrumentation such as creation Bot Registrations, if needed, should be automated (prob except of creating a bot in telegramm). 
I can't find any docs on how to address that but i guess theres 3 options:
1) Use directline api and create own adapter to speak with telegram api.
2) Use Azure script to create Bot registration. But i can't find a place where in web app configure app id and secret, these now  are written in env vars on azure.
3) somehow deploy varios middlewares or enviroments (or slots) for each such registration. Lacking info on this aproach too much.

Maybe also some other options i'm not aware of?